# How to add doubles into a 2d array from a file (Java)?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, java.util.scanner, filereader

All the examples that i have seen involve specifying the number of rows and columns at the start of the file but the method I'm working on reads a file with the following:

```
1.0 2.0
3.0 4.0
```

and using this data creates a 2d array and stores it without specifying the number of rows and columns.

Here's the code I have written:

```
 public static double[][] readMatrixFrom(String file) throws FileNotFoundException {
     Scanner input = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));
     int rows =0;
     int columns =0;

     while(input.hasNextLine()){
         String line = input.nextLine();
         rows++;
         columns = line.length();     
     }
     double[][] d = new double[rows][columns]
     return d;      
}
```

I'm unsure of how to add these values now that I have created the 2d array. i tried this but got an `InputMismatchException`.

```
Scanner s1 = new Scanner(file);
double[][] d = new double[rows][columns]

for (int i= 0;i<rows;i++) {
    for (int j= 0;i<rows;j++) {
         d[i][j] = s1.nextDouble();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to work with arrays of unknown size you should read the data into a `Collection` (such as a `List`). However, `Collection`(s) only work with the wrapper-types; so you will need to copy the elements back into an array of `double`(s) if that is what you *really* need. Something like,

```
public static double[][] readMatrixFrom(String file) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));
    List<List<Double>> al = new ArrayList<>();
    while (input.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = input.nextLine();
        List<Double> ll = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(line);
        while (sc.hasNextDouble()) {
            ll.add(sc.nextDouble());
        }
        al.add(ll);
    }
    double[][] d = new double[al.size()][];
    for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
        List<Double> list = al.get(i);
        d[i] = new double[list.size()];
        for (int j = 0; j < d[i].length; j++) {
            d[i][j] = list.get(j);
        }
    }
    return d;
}
```

Which I tested by creating a file in my home folder with your contents and running it like so

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String file = System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "temp.txt";
    try {
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(readMatrixFrom(file)));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And I get (as I assume you wanted)

```
[[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0]]
```

Answer (score 2):

if you just want to use the basic arrays you can achieve it with something like

```
     Scanner input = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));

     int row=0;
     int col =0;
     String s="";

     //count number of rows
     while(input.hasNextLine()) {
         row++;
         s=input.nextLine();
     }

     //count number of columns
     for(char c: s.toCharArray()) {
         if(c==' ')
             col++;
     }

     col++; // since columns is one greater than the number of spaces

     //close the file
     input.close();

     // and open it again to start reading it from the begining
     input = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));
     //declare a new array
     double[][] d = new double[row][col];   

     int rowNum=0;
     while(input.hasNextLine()) {
         for(int i=0; i< col; i++) {
             d[rowNum][i]= input.nextDouble();
         }
         rowNum++;
     }
```

However if you prefer to use java collection you can avoid reading the file again. Just store the strings in a list and iterate over the list to extract elements from it.

Comment: thanks for this but this is assuming that it will always be a 2x2 array. I tried to get it to work for 2d array of unknown size from a file.

Comment: @A0sXc950 this is with no assumptions, the extra variable was just for my reference which i missed removing from the answer, corrected it now.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your input, Your `columns = line.length();` is returning *7* rather than *2* as it returns the `String` length.

Hence try calculating the no of columns in the row `columns = line.split(" ").length;`

Also while trying to read your input you were using index `i` for the 2nd `for-loop`. It should be like below,

```
for (int i= 0;i<rows;i++) {
    for (int j= 0;j<columns;j++) {
         d[i][j] = s1.nextDouble();
     }
}
```